# debug bridge for iPhone / shell command prompt

Tags: ios, shell, command-line, terminal, adb

For Android there is ADB (Android debug bridge) which allows to get a shell on the connected device:

`adb shell`

Is there something similar for iOS?

I'd like to type some shell commands on my Mac that would be executed on the connected iPhone.
Is there a built-in Terminal on iPhone?

Comment: Here's something that might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983657/iphone-device-debugging

And using Safari: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12587063/ios-6-debug-console-gone

Comment: https://fbidb.io/docs/overview

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything for it built in, but if you are jailbroken or can sideload apps (a.k.a., you have a mac with XCode), you can run a *local* terminal with apps like [MobileTerminal](https://github.com/hbang/NewTerm), which aren't available on the app store.

To access a shell from a computer, if you are jailbroken (and possibly even if you aren't, if you can sideload apps) you can install `openssh` or `openssh-server` from Cydia (I believe it is just called "OpenSSH" in the GUI). Once that is running on your device, you can connect the device over USB and use this [shell script I made called `idb`](https://github.com/wyatt8740/idb) to access a shell, push and pull files, and so on. This sets up a USB link to relay TCP packets from the SSH server on the device, and then 'wraps' around SSH and SCP to perform the required tasks.

You'll have to compile a program to make it work called `iproxy`; this program relays TCP over the USB bus to allow ssh over a cable. The comments in the script I wrote explain how to do this (sorry... I plan to move it into `README.md` eventually).

The program follows most of the syntax of `adb` and implements some of the more commonly used operations of it.

Without jailbreaking, your options are more limited, but it may be possible to do something. I haven't tried since I don't regularly use iOS anymore.

Answer (score 0):

use ssh through network (e.g. Wi-Fi), and iphone/ipad need download and enable ssh service, firstly.